# Hibernate @NotFound caused strange behavior when no records found

Tags: hibernate

could you help here? I've blocked by this issue a couple of days.

**Here is the dependency:**

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <spring.version>5.3.29</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.3.20.Final</hibernate.version>
    <oracle.version>19.3.0.0</oracle.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JDBC driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc10</artifactId>
        <version>${oracle.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
                <artifactId>ucp</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Here is the **entity relationship** between **A,B,C**, all joined by **col_2** and there is no relationship in db for col_2

```
@Table(name = "test_a")
@Entity
public class A implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "col_1")
    private String col1;

    @Column(name = "col_2")
    private String col2;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "col_2", referencedColumnName = "col_2",insertable = false,updatable = false)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private B b;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "col_2", referencedColumnName = "col_2", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private List<C> cs;
}

@Table(name = "test_b")
@Entity
public class B implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "col_1")
    private String col1;

    @Column(name = "col_2")
    private String col2;
}

@Table(name = "test_c")
@Entity
public class C implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "col_1")
    private String col1;

    @Column(name = "col_2")
    private String col2;
}
```

My problem is that when load A entity from db, if there is **no record** for **A.b**, then sometimes it can fetch **A.cs** results but sometimes **A.cs** will be **empty**.

In the wrong case, I observed that it will trigger **multiple** sql querying the table **test_b** and finally it will bind **null** value with sql when query the table test_c

- Seems using bidirectional relationship for col2 can avoid this issue, but still don't know why this issue happens.
- change annotation of A.cs from FetchType.Lazy to FetchType.Eager may be helpful, but it's not applicable for my application.

Here is the test case - https://github.com/angrylittlebird/HelloHibernate

Comment: Seems using bidirectional relationship for col2 can avoid this issue, but still don't know why this issue happens.

Comment: change annotation from FetchType.Lazy to FetchType.Eager may be helpful, but it's not applicable for my application.